# Binding Component's variable to service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-services

I need to take a reference of a variable that is in a service. The variable in the service also can be changed by another function that is in another component. It is hard to explain so let me show you.

SharedService;

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    sharedpages = {
        items: [
                {id: "1", link: "", text: "Epiaş", parent: "0", active: false, tabbed: false},
                {id: "T001", link: "T001", text: "T001 | Abone Bul", parent: "1", active: false, tabbed: false},
               ],
            getAll:  () => {
                return this.sharedpages.items;
            }
        };
    }
```

AppComponent;

```
export class AppComponent {
  public pages;

  constructor(public SharedService: SharedService) {
// The code below just takes sharedpages from sharedservice once then it doesn't takes updates of the sharedpages.
        this.pages = SharedService.sharedpages.getAll();

//The code below also doesn't work
        this.pages = SharedService.sharedpages.items;
      }
    }
```

I want to update pages variable from AppComponent whenever sharedpages from SharedService changes.

for example some other function from another component changed sharedpages.items to blank array. When this happen I want to make pages variable from Appcomponent to blank array too.

Are there any solution for this? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

public pagesChanged$: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
sharedpages = {
    items: [
            {id: "1", link: "", text: "Epiaş", parent: "0", active: false, tabbed: false},
            {id: "T001", link: "T001", text: "T001 | Abone Bul", parent: "1", active: false, tabbed: false},
           ],
        getAll:  () => {
            return this.sharedpages.items;
        }
    };
}
```

AppComponent;

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 public pages;

 constructor(public sharedService: SharedService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.pagesChanged$.subscribe(data => {
        this.pages = data;
    });
}

}
```

And in your component on which the pages getting changed, emit new value

```
export class AnotherComponent {

 constructor(public sharedService: SharedService) {}

onPageChange() {
    this.sharedService.pagesChanged$.next(null); // Emits null as new value
}

}
```

Added a working example 
https://ng-run.com/edit/1zZGSvohchUeEG8dacXt?open=app%2Fanother.component.ts&layout=2

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you so much. It works! Looks like I need to study in these rxjs things a little...

Answer (score 1):

You can go with `Observables/Subscription`. While updating service variable in any component, say

> `updateSharedPages() {
>   // your logic to update goes here 
>   }`

call a method that trigger the changes. This is done using `BehaviorSubject` or `Subject` depending on your use case. Let's take a variable (in your service)

> `updateSharedModelSubject = new Behavior subject<boolean>(true);`

Then

> `triggerSharedModelChange() {
>   this.updateSharedModelSubject.next(this.sharedpages);
>   }`

You can then subscribe to this anywhere in any component.

Answer (score 0):

You need import Inject on Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
```

and import on your component

```
import { SharedService } from './SharedService ';
export class AppComponent {
   console.log(SharedService.sharedpages);
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to add injectable to my question. I am already doing it but it just takes sharedpages at the start of lifecycle and doesnt update my pages variable from appcomponent when sharedpages changes.